# Как проверить несколько подряд идущих байтов на 0x00

Tags: c++, c

Есть массив байтов

```
byte *buffer = new byte[512];
```

Можно ли укоротить проверку нескольких подряд идущих байтов, равны ли они нулю?

```
if((buffer[0] == 0x00) && (buffer[1] == 0x00) && ...)
```

Comment: Создаете буфер, заполненный нулями, и сравниваете его с вашим буффером через memcmp

Comment: а может использовать [all_of](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)?

Comment: Загружать и сравнивать сразу пачкой по 64 байта используя `_mm512_load_epi32` и `_mm512_cmp_epi32_mask` (или аналогичные методы для более распространённых процессоров). Куски массива, не подпадающие под требуемое выравнивание сравнивать как обычно.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Check if a number is non zero using bitwise operators in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3912112/4279). Ещё [Determine if a word has a zero byte](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord)

Answer (score 1):

Просто напишите

```
bool allZero = true;
for (int i = 0; i < сколько_вам_надо; i++)
{
    if (buffer[i] != 0x00)
    {
        allZero = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Читабельность кода намного важнее нескольких выигранных тактов скорости.

Ещё лучше — вынести код в функцию:

```
bool starts_with_zeroes(size_t n, byte* buffer)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] != 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

О векторизации, оптимизации переходов, нужном размере инструкций и прочей нанооптимизации позаботится сам компилятор. Освободите голову для решения реальных проблем (поверьте, в сложных проектах их предостаточно).

Comment: Наверное, условие должно быть != и в таком случае можно цикл сразу же прерывать...

Comment: Тогда уж `if (buffer[i]) {  allZero = false; break; }`

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: И правда.

Comment: @Harry: Действительно :)

Comment: Об векторизации, оптимизации переходов, нужном размере инструкций и прочей оптимизации компилятор не позаботится. В сложных проектах оптимизация производительности является реальной задачей (а для некоторых и проблемой). Правильнее будет  сказать, что ручной оптимизацией стоит заниматься после того, как решены более насущные проблемы, иначе это будет преждевременная оптимизация со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Comment: @VTT: Ну например https://habrahabr.ru/post/339962/. Эпоха «компилятор = ассемблер с человеческим синтаксисом» ушла.

Comment: Допустим это не очень хороший пример. Пусть компиляторы и умеют иногда впихивать продвинутые инструкции, но их возможности по самостоятельной оптимизации сильно ограничены, так как 1) система типов в С++ весьма слабая и не позволяет в compile time собрать много информации 2) нельзя тратить много времени на сборку из-за необходимости переваривать проекты с плохой организацией кода (но все равно все ругаются на время компиляции). Тот же компилятор Интел такой оптимизирующий не потому, что он сам все векторизует, а благодаря идущим в комплекте библиотекам и средствам профилирования.

Comment: @VTT: Тот же интеловский компилятор и даже clang вполне себе умеет в векторизацию там, где она уместна. Ручная оптимизация **без** последующего профилирования чаще всего является в реальности пессимизацией. Поэтому я бы (1) писал прозрачный код без «умных» трюков, (2) доверял бы оптимизирующему компилятору, (3) оптимизировал бы вручную bottleneck'и.

Answer (score 1):

Если С++, можно

```
all_of(buffer,buffer+512,[](byte b){ return b==0; })
```